# MySQL Workbench necessary to have server running to create a database?

Tags: mysql

I installed mySQL workbench and the SQL server. I have successfully got the server running and am wondering if it is necessary to run it while I am creating a database, or if I can work in Workbench with the server not running. I am assuming the server just allows me to test my work and is not necessary in creating it. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this question.

Comment: Server is the main thing - this is where your database storing/query processing etc happens. MySQL Workbench is just a client interface (a GUI) to interact with the server. Without the server running, you cannot connect to any database in Workbench, and hence achieve nothing.

Comment: Are you talking about the designer component/part or about other parts of the MySQL workbench?

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you this answered my question perfectly. @Progman I have no idea what I'm talking about, honestly. I am currently using an interface where I can create a new table and create columns etc...

Answer (score 2):

MySQL workbench is a tool that sends commands (like CREATE DATABASE, CREATE TABLE … ) to the server. The database is stored in the data files managed by the server, so yes, you need to have MySQL's server running in order to create a database/create tables in the database. Possibly you can design your db/tables in MSQLWB (or write the necessary SQL yourself that creates them) without it being connected to the server, but to actually successfully run the command to create your things, you need a running server

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. This answered my question.